# Is there a list for known CLSIDs of the windows registry?

Tags: windows, com, registry, clsid

In the windows registry reside many CLSID values (in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`) such as `{16d51579-a30b-4c8b-a276-0ff4dc41e755}`, many of which may belong to widely known or even built-in applications or libraries. Is there a list or database that contains a mapping of these?

Some usages would be, to present a more meaningful name in a registry viewer along with the key, or checking whether a particular application is present (or was present and not anymore) but has left some keys in the registry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not rely on this mapping.

If you need to go from [ProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542719%28VS.85%29.aspx) to CLSID or the other way around, you can do it by calling [ProgIDFromCLSID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CLSIDFromProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the registry. You could try:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\*" `
    |select PSChildName,`(default`) |ft -auto *
```

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is an alias for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes. There're other words stored in various key values under each CLSID, so you could get cleverer with the PowerShell, but this is a start.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR) is a combination of both `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`  -- and in the case of conflicting keys/values in both hives, the entries in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes` will take precendence and will be the only ones visibile in HKCR.


You can use the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet to create an HKCR drive, similar to the default HKCU and HKLM PSDrives:


`New-PSDrive -name 'HKCR' -PSProvider Registry -Root Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`